# Can I run async code in debug repl?

Tags: node.js, debugging

I'm looking for a debugger that will let me kick-off an async operation in the same context as a breakpoint.

I've tried node v0.12.0's default debugger and also `node-inspector` but both seem to swallow my async attempts - failing to evaluate even simple code like:

```
> setTimeout(function() { console.log('foo') }, 1000);
```

The `node` repl, however, evaluates the above like I expect: 'foo' is printed in the console after a second.

Are async operations not possible with current debug tools? I'd love to drive things like webdriver interactively when debugging tests, etc.

Comment: Do you mean run the async code while the script is breakpointed? If so, you're probably out of luck. That's because the breakpoint stops the event loop and without the event loop async code won't run. If you want to run the async code, resume the debugger.

Comment: After sleeping on it, I think you're of course right. For some reason I swore I'd run async code in chrome while a script was paused, but (trying it this morning) aync code doesn't work there either. I guess I was hoping there was a clever way to pause execution of the current frame while allowing the loop to continue behind the scenes...